# refresh update panel at certain interval

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can i trigger my update panel to refresh after a certain period of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET AJAX Timer control in order to fire an event after a certain period of time.
Checkout this video from ASP.NET official website to find out how to use Timer:
http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-timer-control

Comment: i didnt even notice the timer control in asp.net : p

Answer (score 2):

Use an ASP.Net-Ajax Timer to trigger the UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <%--Typical GridView--%>
        <asp:GridView 
            ID="gvOperations" runat="server" 
            GridLines="None" Width="100%"
            AllowSorting="true" DataSourceID="odsOperations"
            OnRowDataBound="GvOperations_RowDataBound">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="aliceBlue" />
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <%--The Timer that causes the partial postback--%>
        <asp:Timer runat="server" Interval="1500" OnTick="Timer_Tick" />                
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/using_the_ajax_timer_control_a.html

**Update**: Since Matt's link doesn't work anymore, use [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx).

Comment: @TotZam: what  a pity, I have only found [this excerpt](http://myasp101.blogspot.de/2008/09/using-ajax-timer-control-as-updatepanel.html) and posted the MSDN link. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a hidden button to your page
2. Hide the button with CSS
3. Set the button to act as a trigger for the UpdatePanel
4. Set a timer using Javascript to "click" the button.

Add a button to your page with the ID "btnRefresh".

Set the button to act as a trigger on the Update Panel.

Add the following Javascript:

```
function RefreshUpdatePanel() {
    __doPostBack('<%= btnRefresh.ClientID %>','');  
}

setTimeout('RefreshUpdatePanel()', 10000);
```

The setTimeout function will call the RefreshUpdatePanel() function every 10 seconds.  The RefreshUpdatePanel

Comment: Then it sounds like the Timer control is going to be your best bet.